# What does Shor's algorithm tell us about the complexity class of RSA and the DLP?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, quantum-cryptography, shors-algorithm

If quantum computers operate in **BQP** and (using Shor's algorithm) they are able to factor large integers and break the discrete log problem, what does that tell us about the complexity class of these problems?

I just read an article that claims that it is unlikely that RSA or ECC will ever be reduced to **NP**-complete problems, but given Shor's algorithm isn't that impossible?  Or what about the other way: if someone does find such a reduction, does that tell us anything about the relation of **BQP** and **NP**?

Answer (score 3):

That tells us those problems are in BQP.

[This answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/6756/6973)
describes a way of reducing factoring to SAT.
More elaborate approaches will give reductions from ​ RSA or ECC ​ to SAT.

On the other hand, if there is a polynomial-time reduction

*from an NP-hard problem to ​ RSA or ECC* ​ ​ then ​ ​ ​ BQP ∩ [UP](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) ∩ coUP ​ = ​ NP ​ .