# Can quantum computers solve NP-Complete problems?

Tags: quantum-cryptography, grovers-algorithm

As far as I know, quantum computers are able to solve only some of the NP-Problems in polynomial time, using the Grovers algorithm. I read that if one manages to create a reduction of Grovers algorithm on one of the NP-Complete algorithms, for example 3SAT, then it will be a huge milestone, since we could solve all other NP-Complete problems. I also read that current quantum computers lack error-correcting qubits to create a reduction of Grovers algorithm on 3SAT. What would be a sufficient amount of qubits to solve such problem and what amount do we currently have?

Comment: This has been asked before. But better to be asked [quantum.se](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=NP). Grover just produces quadratic speed, nothing more. Is there any specific reason that you have been asked here instead of quantumcomputing.se?

Comment: Crypto-related can be asked like [What does Shor's algorithm tell us about the complexity class of RSA and the DLP?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37522/18298), [Are cryptographic hash functions quantum secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44390/18298)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is realted to solving NP related problems with QC. Is not a specific problem related to cryptography. Therefore either to be asked in CS.SE, quantumcomputing.se or should concentrate a specific problem in Cryptography.

Comment: Is this your question on quantumcomputing [Can quantum computers solve NP-complete problems?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16506/4866), asked two hours ago. Could you delete this copy?

Comment: short answer, though: no, not as far as we know. Grover changes nothing to that since it only provides a quadratic speedup. No NP complete problem is known to be solvable using a quantum computer, only specific problems outside of P, and inside NP (intersect) co-NP, such as factoring and discrete log, are known to be solved in polynomial time with a quantum computer.